# Crontab stops halfway

Tags: cron

Running a python script on raspbian every min, here the crontab line:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /something/code.py >> /something/code.txt
```

However, code.txt shows me that it stops halfway in the code. I.e:

```
Hello 1

Hello 2
```

When run manually, I get more hello's, no errors.

Things I've done:

1. Added: `#!/usr/bin/python3` to top of script
2. `chmod +x` the script
3. used just `python3` vs `/usr/bin/python3`
4. Ran a sample `****` (`echo hello world >> text.txt`) and it works, but python doesn't work :(

Any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: the error should be inside code.py.

Comment: Yes, the error is in your Python code. Try running two instances of the code at once in two separate shell sessions, each appending its output to the same file.  How long does the code take to complete a run?

Comment: Try capturing the error output from the script by adding something like `2>/something/code-errors.txt`. My guess is that something in the script assumes some environment setup that isn't done by cron (it provides a very minimal environment to its jobs), but without the script and/or its error output, there's no way to do more than guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your script needs some environmental variables that crontab doesn't set by default. Keep in mind that crontab environment variables are very limited.

There are several approaches to set your environment variables in cron:

1. Set each variable you need in your script.
2. Export a completer `PATH` than the default set by your contrab at the beginning of your script or before calling your script in crontab.
3. Source your profile: `. $HOME/.profile`.